# Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

Tags: java, smtp, gmail

While sending mail, I am getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending
> failed;   nested exception is:    class javax.mail.MessagingException:
> Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

Here is my code:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("email", "password");
        }
    });

try {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("email"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse(this.to));
    message.setSubject("Testing");
    message.setText("Hey, this is the testing email.");

    Transport.send(message);
    // ...
}
```

What is the cause of this error, and how can the problem be resolved?

Comment: Check http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: I tried the same code but still m getting the error:           javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 4sm28216799pbn.23 - gsmtp
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1020)at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:716)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:388)
 at rapid.mail.main(mail.java:60)                                                                  This line for starttls is there then why m getting same error: properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Comment: Try with the latest jar version JavaMail 1.4.7

Comment: no progress same error

Comment: Change the port number to 587.

Comment: I changed the port number to 587 getting same error

Answer (score 19):

You need to tell it that you are using SSL:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

In case you miss anything, here is working code:

```
String  d_email = "address@gmail.com",
            d_uname = "Name",
            d_password = "urpassword",
            d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            d_port  = "465",
            m_to = "toAddress@gmail.com",
            m_subject = "Indoors Readable File: " + params[0].getName(),
            m_text = "This message is from Indoor Positioning App. Required file(s) are attached.";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    SMTPAuthenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
    session.setDebug(true);

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        msg.setSubject(m_subject);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to));

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
            transport.connect(d_host, Integer.valueOf(d_port), d_uname, d_password);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();

        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: i am getting below exception. can you tell me where it is failing
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
 class javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
 at sendMail.SendMail4.execute(SendMail4.java:70)
 at sendMail.sel.main(sel.java:10)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what is the `d_uname` field utility. In the other side, in the connection instruction, we should pass the email rather than the user name : `transport.connect(d_host, Integer.valueOf(d_port), d_email, d_password);`. Also, you had better show the package from where comes the class `SMTPAuthenticator` in the code, or specify the API required alternatively on the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I have been experiencing this issue when debugging using NetBeans, even executing the actual jar file. Antivirus would block sending email. You should temporarily disable your antivirus during debugging or exclude NetBeans and the actual jar file from being scanned. In my case, I'm using Avast.

See this link on how to Exclude : [How to Add File/Website Exception into avast! Antivirus 2014](http://www.getavast.net/support/managing-exceptions/)

It works for me.

Comment: Could you describe in more details the connection between SMTP response and the antivirus?

Comment: @carlodurso: Antivirus, (in my case AVAST) has features on blocking programs that use the port in and out on the suspicion of security threat. So better exclude your jar file from being blocked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was Avast Antivirus interfering with the connection.
Actions to disable this feature:
Avast -> Settings-> Components -> Mail Shield (Customize) -> SSL scanning -> uncheck "Scan SSL connections".

Answer (score 1):

Port 465 is for "smtp over SSL".

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

```
[...] For example, use
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "888");
to set the mail.smtp.port property, which is of type int.

Note that if you're using the "smtps" protocol to access SMTP over SSL, 
all the properties would be named "mail.smtps.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

What i did was i commented out the

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
```

Because apparently for G-mail you did not need it. Then if you haven't already done this you need to create an app password in G-mail for your program. I did that and it worked perfectly. Here this link will show you how: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833.