# The e-mail is not sent. Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com

Tags: maximo

My Maximo System Properties are:

```
mail.smtp.host : smtp.gmail.com
port: 465
user: user@gmail.com
password: '***'
mxe.adminEmail : user@gmail.com
```

I am unable to send mail to a gmail user through maximo. Please guide  configuration steps so that mail will be received to a gmail id.

I checked with exchange server. It shows following error:

```
> ** Email test: Connected to e-mail accountparul.ciet@gmail.com DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.3.2 DEBUG: getProvider() returning
> javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3. POP3Store,Sun
> Microsystems, Inc] DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "smtp.gmail.com",
> port 465, isSSL false javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;  
> nested exception is:
>         java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
>         at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:161)
>         at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:233)
>         at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
>         at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
>         at psdi.tools.TestEmail.<init>(Unknown Source)
>         at psdi.tools.TestEmail.main(Unknown Source)
> 
> C:\IBM\SMP\maximo\tools\maximo\internal>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378133/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-port-465-response-1)

Answer (score 1):

For Maximo, you may need to set up additional configuration to get email to work over SMTP over SSL (port 465):

http://maximocore.blogspot.com/2012/10/maximo-e-mail-listener-configuring-for.html

In your system properties, review the following settings:

```
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.port=465
mxe.smtp.password=xyz
mxe.smtp.user=user@gmail.com
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
```