# Getting javax.mail.SendFailedException while Sending attached Mail Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have Written a code for Sending mail having Attachment file but getting  **javax.mail.SendFailedException** Exception . below is the code which I have written. Can anyone Correct me that why i am getting Exception
Below is Exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sendMail.sendMail2.execute(sendMail2.java:102)
    at sendMail.sel.main(sel.java:17)
```

Below is Mail Class

```
package sendMail;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


public class sendMail2 {
    public static void execute() throws Exception {

        final String username = "sender@gmail.com";
        final String password = "*********";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("recepient@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();  
            messageBodyPart1.setText("This is message body");  

            //4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object      
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();  

            String filename = "C:/Selenium Workspace/FMC360Automation/test-output/emailable-report.html";//change accordingly  
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);  
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));  
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);  

            //5) create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object      
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);  
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);  

            //6) set the multiplart object to the message object  
            message.setContent(multipart); 

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is Basic Java Selenium program

```
package sendMail;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class sel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=sjPLVue4OI2IuATgkaWwCw");
        try {
            //Sendmail.execute("C:/Selenium Workspace/FMC360Automation/test-output/emailable-report.html");
                sendMail2.execute();
            driver.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378133/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-port-465-response-1)

Comment: @Berger thanks for comment but same exception I am getting

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: I am sending from my local system

Answer (score 0):

Login to your google account using your gmail credential which you are using to send mail from selenium scripts. Then browse https://myaccount.google.com/security?hl=en#connectedapps and enable 'Allow less secure apps'

Comment: done but again the same exceptions. Is my office network affecting on this script?